# How were Microsoft GW-BASIC "protected" files encoded?

Tags: microsoft-basic

Microsoft GW-BASIC on IBM compatibles allowed flags to the `SAVE` command, to indicate the manner in which a file should be written out.

As I recall, it allowed for no flag to write a standard tokenized format, `,A` to write a plain-text ASCII BASIC listing, and `,P` to write a "protected" file.

"Protected" files looked like gibberish on disk even compared to the tokenized files, and the interpreter would at least refuse to `LIST` the source code. As I recall the file size also wasn't the same. They did however run just fine when given to the interpreter.

**How were such "protected" files encoded?** What about them was different compared to an ordinary tokenized save (no flag)?

Answer (score 13):

The files are encoded as follows:

- the first byte is 0xFE to indicate that it’s a protected tokenized file (0xFF for a regular tokenized file);
- the remainder of the file is encoded using exclusive-ors with two keys, embedded in the interpreter (or in the ROM, for BASICA).

The two keys are

```
Key1    db    9Ah, 0F7h, 19h, 83h,  24h, 63h, 43h, 83h,  75h, 0CDh, 8Dh, 84h, 0A9h
Key2    db    7Ch,  88h, 59h, 74h, 0E0h, 97h, 26h, 77h, 0C4h,  1Dh, 1Eh
```

When decoding, two counters are stored in `CH` and `CL`, starting respectively at 0x0D and 0x0B (the lengths of the keys); each stored byte is then replaced with (*encoded* – `CL`) ^ `Key1[CH – 1]` ^ `Key2[CL – 1]` + `CH`, `CL` and `CH` decrementing every time a byte is processed until they hit 0 (after the calculation), when they are reset to their starting value (independently). Encoding is the opposite: with the same loop, each plain-text byte is replaced with (*decoded* – `CH`) ^ `Key1[CH – 1]` ^ `Key2[CL – 1]` + `CL`.

So the size of the files should be identical. The `LIST` limitation is presumably implemented in the interpreter.

See [Deciphering GW-BASIC / BASICA protected programs](https://slions.net/threads/deciphering-gw-basic-basica-protected-programs.50/) for details.

Comment: I seem to recall a POKE command to un-protect the code from within the interpreter, but I could be mistaken.  It was pre-internet days, after all and I can't imagine where I would've seen it or learned about it, yet the memory seems real.  Perhaps I saw something on a BBS somewhere.

Comment: @Bill that’s quite likely, the documentation in `UNPBAS11.ZIP` mentions other decryption schemes, and says “Still other schemes employ a
`POKE` or `BLOAD` after loading the protected program into the interpreter,
which may or may not be allowed, depending on the interpreter.”

Comment: @BillHileman: Early versions of MSBASIC may have allowed a `poke` to disable protection, but later versions severely restrict the set of actions that can be done in immediate mode--probably because MS realized that people were using `poke` to bypass protected mode.